# A difficulty in understanding a use of Cauchy Schwartz inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

This is the proof:

[image]

I do not understand how $\operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle \leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$, using Cauchy Schwartz inequality,I know that it states that $\langle x,y\rangle|  \leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\|$ could anyone clarify this for me please?

Thanks!

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz is $|\left<x,y\right>|\le\|x\|\|y\|$. So you also need $\text{Re}\left<x,y\right>\le|\left<x,y\right>|$.

Comment: $$ \begin{align} & Re<x,y>  \leq ||x||.||y|| \\ & \operatorname{Re}\langle x,y\rangle \leq \|x\|\cdot\|y\| \end{align}$$ I found the first line above and changed it to the second. That's the right way to code this. $\qquad$

Comment: Thank u @MichaelHardy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any complex number $z=u+iv$, we have
$$ \Re z=u\leq \sqrt{u^2+v^2}=|z|$$
Setting $z=\langle x,y\rangle$ and using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we get
$$ \Re\langle x,y\rangle\leq |\langle x,y\rangle|\leq \|x\|\|y\|$$